# Retrieving the shape of a multidimensional array in D

Tags: multidimensional-array, d

```
auto getMultidimensionalArrayShape( T )( T array )
{
  static assert( isArray!( T ) );

  // Retrieve the shape of the input array and double check that
  // the arrays from a same dimension have the same length.
  size_t[] shape;
  // ...

  return shape;
}

getMultidimensionalArrayShape( [1, 2, 3] )  //< returns [3]
getMultidimensionalArrayShape( [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] )  //< returns [3][2]
// and so on...
```

Naively, I would iterate in a depth-first manner to retrieve the size of each array at the indices 0, then I'll check if the other arrays from the same dimension matches in length with what I've found at index 0, just to make sure that everything is consistent, but I'm thinking that there must be a better way... does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I've ended up writing. Basically I'm collecting all the arrays of a same depth level and retrieve their dimension size, after making sure that they're all equal.
Sounds like it's working nicely, the only thing is that I'm not sure what to do when the length of depthLevelArrays is equal to 0? Does it even make sense or should I just throw an exception?

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;


void internal( T )( T[] depthLevelArrays, ref size_t[] shape )
{
  if ( depthLevelArrays.length == 0 )
      writeln( "what to do here?" );

  static if ( isArray!( ForeachType!( T ) ) )
  {
    ForeachType!( T )[] children;
    size_t dimensionSize = depthLevelArrays[0].length;
    foreach ( element; depthLevelArrays )
    {
      if ( element.length != dimensionSize )
        throw new Exception( "Shape is not uniform" );

      foreach ( child; element )
        children ~= child;
    }

    internal( children, shape );
  }
  else
  {
    size_t dimensionSize = depthLevelArrays[0].length;
    foreach ( element; depthLevelArrays )
      if ( element.length != dimensionSize )
        throw new Exception( "Shape is not uniform" );
  }

  shape ~= dimensionSize;
}


auto getMultidimensionalArrayShape( T )( T array )
{
  static assert( isArray!( T ) );
  size_t[] shape;
  internal( [array], shape );
  return shape;
}


void main()
{
  immutable auto array1d = [1.0, 2.5, 3.4];
  auto shape1 = getMultidimensionalArrayShape( array1d );
  writeln( "shape1: ", shape1 ); //< [3]

  int[5][2] array2d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];
  auto shape2 = getMultidimensionalArrayShape( array2d );
  writeln( "shape2: ", shape2 );  //< [5][2]

  auto shape3 = getMultidimensionalArrayShape(
      [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
      [[9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]],
      [[17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]] );
  writeln( "shape3: ", shape3 ); //< [2][4][3]

  const int[5][4][3][2] array4d;
  auto shape4 = getMultidimensionalArrayShape( array4d );
  writeln( "shape4: ", shape4 ); //< [5][4][3][2]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This calls for a recursive solution.

```
template depthOf(T){
    static if(isIterable!T)
        enum depthOf=1+depthOf!(ForeachType!T);
    else
        enum depthOf=0;
}

immutable(long)[] getMultidimensionalArrayShape(bool verify=true,T)(T array){
    static assert(isArray!T);
    static if(!isArray!(ForeachType!T)){
        return [array.length];
    }else{
        if(0==array.length)
            return [0L].replicate(depthOf!T).idup;
        const elementDimension=array[0].getMultidimensionalArrayShape();
        static if(verify){
            foreach(child;array[1..$]){
                if(child.getMultidimensionalArrayShape()!=elementDimension)
                    throw new Exception("Shape is not uniform");
            }
        }
        return (array.length~elementDimension).idup;
    }
}
```

Actually, it's not really a recursion, since no function calls itself(functions call other functions created from the same template). Static recursion is a better name.

Comment: Thanks Idan! I'm not totally sure but by reading your code I feel like your verify operation doesn't apply to all the arrays of a same level but to only the first branch traversed. Also the resulting shape is reversed, but that's not much of an issue. Meanwhile I digged on my side too and ended up finding a nice solution I think, cf. my answer.